# Writing Parquet in Azure Blob Storage: "One of the request inputs is not valid"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, parquet

I'm trying to write a simple DataFrame in `parquet` format to **Azure Blob Storage**.
Note that the following code snippets work in local, so my guess is that it has to be something related with Azure libraries. I tried as well with `delta` format and it works (even if it uses `parquet` under the hood).

Using Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12.10, OpenJDK 1.8.0_292.

I set up my Spark session as usual, something like:

```sh
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell \
  (...cluster settings...) \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<account>.blob.core.windows.net="${AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_KEY}" \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.wasb.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.Wasb \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.wasb.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem \
  --conf spark.delta.logStore.class=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.storage.AzureLogStore \
  --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:2.7.0,com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.8.0,com.azure:azure-storage-common:12.8.0,com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage:2.0.0,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.8.0
  (...other irrelevant settings...)
```

I tried other versions for `azure-storage-blob`, `azure-storage-common` and `azure-storage` packages, all resulting in the same problem.

To reproduce the problem I create a simple dataframe and write it to the storage:

```scala
val columns = Seq("language", "users_count")
val data = Seq(("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000"))
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF(columns: _*)
df.show
// +--------+-----------+                                                                                                                                  
// |language|users_count|
// +--------+-----------+
// |    Java|      20000|
// |  Python|     100000|
// |   Scala|       3000|
// +--------+-----------+

df.write.parquet("wasb://<container>@<account>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>")
```

When writing on parquet format I get the `com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid` exception:

```
21/09/21 13:38:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 83) (10.244.6.3 executor 6): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem$FolderRenamePending.execute(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.rename(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1997)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:531)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:502)
        at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:260)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1473)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:286)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: One of the request inputs is not valid.
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:162)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:307)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:177)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopyFromBlob(CloudBlob.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.startCopyFromBlob(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2449)
        ... 20 more
```

Any hints or ideas on what is causing it or what to do to make it work?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just change **wasb** to **abfss** and **blob** to **dfs** where ever used.
Sample code:
**wasb**://@.**blob**.core.windows.net/ to
**abfss**://@.**dfs**.core.windows.net

This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Two things helped me to write to Azure storage using WASB protocol:

1. storage container should be Data Lake Gen1 (tried Gen2 and failed)
2. you need to add the following dependency/jar:

   org.codehaus.jackson
        jackson-mapper-lgpl
        1.9.13

I had to use WASB (due to my version of hadoop (2.9.2) does not support ABFS), but if you have hadoop-2.10.1+, please use ABFS.

Comment: So you think it is a problem with the storage, not the libraries? I've only tried with BlobStorage, using both Hadoop 2.7 and 3.2 (WASB). I'll have a look at your suggestions.